# Getting error on passing a variable through constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

when I am running my typescript file in Angular I am getting error in console

> Error : compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters
>   for SearchNameComponent: ([object Object], ?).

I am posting my full code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {StudentSearchService , Students} from '../service/student-search.service';
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-name',
  templateUrl: './search-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-name.component.css'],
  providers: [StudentSearchService],
})
export class SearchNameComponent implements OnInit {

  std: Students[];
  data: any = '';
  constructor( public students: StudentSearchService  , data: any) {

    this.std = students.getstudent();
    console.log(data);
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: The Angular DI doesn't know what you want it to provide for `data` when it instantiates the component

Comment: Since you have `data` as a property you shouldn't need it in the constructor.

Comment: can you please show your  StudentSearchService file so i will help you

Comment: post studentSearchservice code

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you have defined the constructor to accept 2 arguments while only one is being passed.

Either make the second argument optional or remove the second argument from the constructor.

example

```
export class SearchNameComponent implements OnInit {

  std: Students[];
  data: any = '';
  constructor( public students: StudentSearchService) {

    this.std = students.getstudent();
    console.log(data);
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```